# How can three dissimilarity matrices be combined into a comprehensive one?

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching, similarity, unsupervised-learning

I have, say 10 images of same dimensions (100-by-100), and I want to compare these images to see how similar each of them to be with others, i.e. I want finally to get a dissimilarity matrix (10-by-10). Now I plan to compare them from three different perspectives or properties (texture, mutual information(pixel-by-pixel correspondence), histogram), so I can get three dissimilarity matrices. And the data range are obviously different for these three matrices; maybe first one is Euclidean distance, and second one represents probability... My question is: after I get the three same size dissimilarity matrices, how can them be combined into a comprehensive matrix to summarize the dissimilarity structure of input images? Sorry for that I can't provide practical result for now, but I think my question is now clear enough.

Comment: You could do a weighted sum of the 3 matricies. You would need to weight each matrix differently to account for the differences in measurement ranges. This weighting may need to be non-linear.

Comment: Thank you. But the key is that these dissimilarity matrices have different meanings, such as one is in the sense of probability, but the other may be in the form of euclidean distance. Perhaps I need to first convert them into the same framework?

Comment: When I say weighting what I mean any function that puts them into the same framework. If you put them into some sort of probabilistic framework then you would could justify multiplying them (elementwise) by assuming independence. If you put them into some framework where addition makes sense then you could add them.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. My results include 3 dissimilarity or similarity matrices. First is Euclidean distance matrix, and its value range is from 0 to 1. Second is a correlation coefficient matrix. And third is also an Euclidean distance matrix, but have different value ranges, 0 - 100. Then can you give me a concrete example about how to put these three matrices into the same framework, where addition or multiplying make sense. Thank you.